# Arbitrary \left \right delimiters

Tags: math-mode, symbols, packages, delimiters

Is there a package that would allow me to use other symbols/any symbol apart from the (among others) usual delimiters `() [] {} |` with `\left` and `\right`?

For example, `\(\left\int f(x) dx \right.\)` would adapt the size of the integral sign to the height of `f(x)`.

Comment: You have `scalerel` package to do something *similar*, but I don't understand why would you want that.

Comment: This would be likely to require a font with an “extensible” version of the integral sign (compare with the root sign, which has an extensible version), but I’m afraid such a character would look pretty horrible.  I’ve never seen anything similar in print, but maybe you have.  Also, maybe you don’t actually want arbitrarily large integral signs, but only up to some maximum.

Comment: see [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2414/how-can-i-have-a-bigger-integral-int-delimiter) and [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109699/how-can-i-create-a-new-extensible-symbol)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As Manuel indicates, my `scalerel` package can be used.  However, I don't necessarily recommend this approach except in unusual circumstances.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\def\x{\begin{bmatrix*}1&1\\1&1\end{bmatrix*}}
\[{\scalerel*[2.2ex]{\int}{\x}}_{\!\!\!x=0}^{\infty}\x\,dx\]

\def\x{\begin{bmatrix*}1&1&1\\1&1&1\\1&1&1\end{bmatrix*}}
\[{\scalerel*[2.2ex]{\int}{\x}}_{\!\!\!x=0}^{\infty}\x\,dx\]

\def\x{\begin{bmatrix*}1&1&1&1\\1&1&1&1\\1&1&1&1\\1&1&1&1\end{bmatrix*}}
\[{\scalerel*[2.2ex]{\int}{\x}}_{\!\!\!x=0}^{\infty}\x\,dx\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Whereas the above use of `\scalerel` applies a maximum width of 2.2ex to the integral sign, the `\stretchrel` macro could be used as an alternative, with the optional argument providing the maximum aspect ratio (in %), e.g., `\stretchrel[250]{}{}`.

---

ADDENDUM:

By combining the above approach with a more vertically oriented integral sign ([Integral Sign $\int...$](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170028/integral-sign-int/170033#170033)),
one may find a result slightly less offensive to the eye.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\rint}{\ThisStyle{\rotatebox{15}{$\SavedStyle\!\int\!\!\!$}}}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\parskip 1ex

\begin{document}
\def\x{\begin{bmatrix*}1&1\\1&1\end{bmatrix*}}
\[{\scalerel*[4ex]{\rint}{\x}}_{\!x=0}^{\!\infty}\x\,dx\]

\def\x{\begin{bmatrix*}1&1&1\\1&1&1\\1&1&1\end{bmatrix*}}
\[{\scalerel*[4ex]{\rint}{\x}}_{\!\!x=0}^{\!\infty}\x\,dx\]

\def\x{\begin{bmatrix*}1&1&1&1\\1&1&1&1\\1&1&1&1\\1&1&1&1\end{bmatrix*}}
\[{\scalerel*[4ex]{\rint}{\x}}_{\!\!x=0}^{\!\infty}\x\,dx\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is the 2nd time today (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/251879/increasing-summation-size-in-continued-fraction/251911#251911) I violated egreg's religious beliefs:  "increasing summation and integral signs is against my religion."  (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/251879/increasing-summation-size-in-continued-fraction) and "The integral symbol never stretches to cover the integrand" (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/104414/math-spacing-in-tex-gyre-pagella)  Better get that brimstone heated up...

Comment: I upvoted this answer because it deserves it, but I confirm that, IMHO, the stretched-out integral sign looks horrible… ;-)

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti No argument from me.

Answer (score 18):

It occured to me, yesterday, that there *does* exist (at least) one font which includes glyphs for building a truly extensible integral sign: it is the PostScript Symbol font (`psyr`), which has such glyphs in positions 243 (octal '363, hexadecimal "F3), 244 (octal '364, hexadecimal "F4) and 245 (octal '365, hexadecimal "F5).  Thus an approach along these lines is possible too.

Unfortunately, the `.tfm` file for the PS Symbol font, `psyr.tfm`, does not include the necessary information to build the extensible sign from these glyphs (at least, this is the case for the `psyr.tfm` file included in the distribution to which I can have access right now, a TeXLive 2013—I cannot explain here why I am presently limited to this).  However, it’s no big deal to augment the `.tfm` file to provide the information that is missing.  An alternative approach, of course, would be to use a virtual font: this is no big deal too, but for the moment I don’t deem this necessary, as the augmented `.tfm` file should not hamper the use of the `psyr` font for other purposes.  On the other hand, it is true that `psyr.tfm` does not define `\fontdimen7`, and that loading it, as we will do below, can make it impossible to fiddle with the font parameters if the `psyr.tfm` is loaded again later; so, using a virtual font might prove necessary, but for the moment, I repeat, I’ll leave this to a possible future enhancement.

Having said that, let us proceed with step-by-step instructions on how to get our extensible integral sign in print!

---

### Building the augmented `psyr.tfm` file

Please note that this process (actually, a slightly more general one, which defines a virtual font) has already been described in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/111802/69818).

In order to modify a `.tfm` file, we need first to convert it to a human-readable form, modify it in this form, and convert the modified file back into `.tfm` format.  The human-readable form is a Property List (`.pl`) file; you can convert a `.tfm` file to a `.pl` file with the `tftopl` command-line utility and a `.pl` file back to a `.tfm` file with—guess what?—the `pltotf` program.

So, let’s start to construct our modified `psyr.tfm` file.  Move to a directory of your choice and, from the command line, type the command:

```
tftopl psyr.tfm psyr.pl
```

This will create the human-readable file `psyr.pl` in your current directory.  Open this file: its first few lines should read

```
(FAMILY SYMBOL)
(CODINGSCHEME FONTSPECIFIC)
(DESIGNSIZE R 10.0)
(COMMENT DESIGNSIZE IS IN POINTS)
(COMMENT OTHER SIZES ARE MULTIPLES OF DESIGNSIZE)
(CHECKSUM O 16264261360)
(FONTDIMEN
   (SLANT R 0.0)
   (SPACE R 0.25)
   (STRETCH R 0.3)
   (SHRINK R 0.1)
   (XHEIGHT R 0.4)
   (QUAD R 1.0)
   )
(CHARACTER O 40
   (CHARWD R 0.25)
   )
```

and so on.  First of all, since we are going to modify the file, it is a good idea to delete the line that says `(CHECKSUM O 16264261360)`: thus the checksum will be recomputed when we convert the file back to `.tfm` format.

Next, let’s begin with our patches.  Go down to the definition of `CHARACTER O 362`, that is, to the lines that read

```
(CHARACTER O 362
   (CHARWD R 0.274)
   (CHARHT R 0.904)
   (CHARDP R 0.104)
   (CHARIC R 0.017)
   )
```

Modify these lines by adding another line below `(CHARIC R 0.017)`, so that the whole definition of the character '362 (octal) becomes

```
(CHARACTER O 362
   (CHARWD R 0.274)
   (CHARHT R 0.904)
   (CHARDP R 0.104)
   (CHARIC R 0.017)
   (NEXTLARGER O 363)
   )
```

(we added the line `(NEXTLARGER O 363)`).  Actually, this step isn’t truly necessary (see below), but I prefer to add redundant information to the font itself.  Now move down to the next character, whose original definition is

```
(CHARACTER O 363
   (CHARWD R 0.686)
   (CHARHT R 0.904)
   (CHARDP R 0.084)
   (CHARIC R 0.029)
   )
```

Modify it so that it becomes

```
(CHARACTER O 363
   (CHARWD R 0.686)
   (CHARHT R 0.904)
   (CHARDP R 0.084)
   (CHARIC R 0.029)
   (VARCHAR
      (TOP O 363)
      (BOT O 365)
      (REP O 364)
      )
   )
```

(five lines have been added).  This is the change that tells TeX how to build an extensible integral sign from the glyphs contained in slots 243, 244 and 245 (decimal) of the font; this extensible character is conventionally assigned to slot 243 itself.

That’s all: save the modified `psyr.pl` file (always, of course, in your current, private directory!) and convert it back to a `.tfm` file; say

```
pltotf psyr.pl psyr.tfm
```

so that the augmented file `psyr.tfm` is saved in the current directory too.  This augmented file should be placed in a position on the file system where it takes precedence over the original `psyr.tfm` file: one possibility is to place it alongside (that is, in the same directory of) the `.tex` file you want to compile.  Another choice is your local texmf tree, but remember that, if you do so, the modified `psyr.tfm` file will be used for *all* your documents that happen to use the symbol font, and this might create problems: I would recommend this choice *only* if you switched to a solution that employs a virtual font instead.

---

### Defining a new delimiter in TeX

This part of the construction is easy, as NFSS offers you all the necessary tools.  You can just mimick the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{psy}{\hyphenchar\font \m@ne}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{psy}{m}{n}{<-> psyr }{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{myExtensibleIntegralSign}{U}{psy}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\extenintsign}{\mathop}
    {myExtensibleIntegralSign}{"F2}
    {myExtensibleIntegralSign}{"F3} % also "{operators}{0}" would work

\makeatother



\begin{document}

Text before.
\[
    \left\extenintsign
        \begin{pmatrix}
            a & b & c & d  \\
            e & f & g & h  \\
            i & j & k & l  \\
            m & n & o & p  \\ 
        \end{pmatrix}
    \right.
    dt
\]
Text after.

\end{document}
```

Remember that, in order for this to work, the modified `psyr.tfm` file must be loaded instead of the original one.  If everything goes as expected, you will get the following output:

[image: Output of the first code sample]

Let us describe briefly what we have done.

1. The first three lines of code after `\makeatletter` define a new
   symbol font called `myExtensibleIntegralSign`, that points to the
   `psyr` font.  The family (or, in NFSS terminology, math group)
   number for this font is allocated automatically by
   `\DeclareSymbolFont`; in this particular case, it turns out that
   `myExtensibleIntegralSign` corresponds to family 4, but we are not
   concerned at all with this, since `\DeclareMathDelimiter` itself
   “knows” which is the right family number to use.
2. The `\DeclareMathDelimiter` declaration defines a new delimiter,
   called `\extenintsign`, that can be used after `\left` or `\right`
   in the usual way.  Note that, in our setting, the “large” variant of
   the delimiter (`"F3`) will never be used, because we included in the
   `.tfm` file itself information that leads from the “small” variant
   (`"F2`) to the larger one, which is also the extensible one; thus,
   specifying `{operators}{0}` as the last two arguments of
   `\DeclareMathDelimiter` would work too (note that the `operators`
   font corresponds to family 0), but including the pointer to the
   large, and extensible, variant makes the code more robust, in case
   the `.tfm` file lacked this information.
3. Finally, in the equation we use our brand new `\extenintsign`
   delimiter in an ordinary `\left`/`\right` construction.  Please, tell
   me—after all this blather—that it looks at least a *tiny bit* better
   than Steven’s stretched-out integral sign! (:-)

---

### Adding limits

It remains to add the integration limits to our extensible integral sign.  This is not trivial given the following two unfortunate circumstances:

- TeX records `\left` and `\right` delimiters inside math lists as
  “boundary items”; but a boundary item is not an atom, hence it cannot
  carry subscripts or superscripts by itself.
- An Op atom, on the other hand, can correspond to at most two printed
  symbols, that is, a small variant, used in non-display style, and a
  large variant, used in display style.  TeX offers no provision for
  taking into account the size of the following subformula (the choice
  between the two sizes is based uniquely on the current style), and no
  more for making the size of the Op atom grow with it; just think of
  the fact that no syntactic provision, either, is made to determine
  where such a subformula would end.

This means that we must have recourse to some trick, in a way or another.  Here is one of the possibilities (it is a complete, compilable example):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{psy}{\hyphenchar\font \m@ne}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{psy}{m}{n}{<-> psyr }{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{myExtensibleIntegralSign}{U}{psy}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\extenintsign}{\mathop}
    {myExtensibleIntegralSign}{"F2}
    {myExtensibleIntegralSign}{"F3} % also "{operators}{0}" would work

\newcommand*\extenint[3]{\mathpalette\@extenint{{#1}{#2}{#3}}}
\newcommand*\@extenint[2]{\@@extenint#1#2}
\newcommand*\@@extenint[4]{%
    \mathop{\hbox{$#1\left\extenintsign\vphantom{#4}\right.\n@space$}}%
        \ilimits@ % honor amsmath.sty
        \ifx\@empty#2\@empty\else _{\!#2}\fi
        \ifx\@empty#3\@empty\else ^{\,#3}\fi
    #4
}
% We define the following two commands for testing purposes only:
\newcommand*\forcelimits  {\let \ilimits@ \limits  }
\newcommand*\forcenolimits{\let \ilimits@ \nolimits}

\makeatother



\begin{document}

With one row:
\begin{align*}
    \extenint{-\infty}{+\infty}
        {\begin{pmatrix}
            a & b & c & d  \\
        \end{pmatrix}}
    dt
    && \forcelimits
    \extenint{-\infty}{+\infty}
        {\begin{pmatrix}
            a & b & c & d  \\
        \end{pmatrix}}
    dt
\end{align*}

With two rows:
\begin{align*}
    \extenint{-\infty}{+\infty}
        {\begin{pmatrix}
            a & b & c & d  \\
            e & f & g & h  \\
        \end{pmatrix}}
    dt
    && \forcelimits
    \extenint{-\infty}{+\infty}
        {\begin{pmatrix}
            e & f & g & h  \\
            a & b & c & d  \\
        \end{pmatrix}}
    dt
\end{align*}

With four rows:
\begin{align*}
    \extenint{-\infty}{+\infty}
        {\begin{pmatrix}
            a & b & c & d  \\
            e & f & g & h  \\
            i & j & k & l  \\
            m & n & o & p  \\ 
        \end{pmatrix}}
    dt
    && \forcelimits
    \extenint{-\infty}{+\infty}
        {\begin{pmatrix}
            e & f & g & h  \\
            a & b & c & d  \\
            i & j & k & l  \\
            m & n & o & p  \\ 
        \end{pmatrix}}
    dt
\end{align*}

With six rows:
\begin{align*}
    \extenint{-\infty}{+\infty}
        {\begin{pmatrix}
            a & b & c & d  \\
            e & f & g & h  \\
            i & j & k & l  \\
            m & n & o & p  \\ 
            q & r & s & t  \\ 
            u & v & w & x  \\ 
        \end{pmatrix}}
    dt
    && \forcelimits
    \extenint{-\infty}{+\infty}
        {\begin{pmatrix}
            e & f & g & h  \\
            a & b & c & d  \\
            i & j & k & l  \\
            m & n & o & p  \\ 
            q & r & s & t  \\ 
            u & v & w & x  \\ 
        \end{pmatrix}}
    dt
\end{align*}

However, this does not look good:
\begin{align*}
    \extenint{-\infty}{+\infty}{dt}
    && \forcelimits
    \extenint{-\infty}{+\infty}{dt}
\end{align*}
(I mean, at least the left alternative: the right one could still look
acceptable).  Indeed, comparison with the ``normal'' integral
\begin{align*}
    \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} dt
    && \forcelimits
    \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} dt
\end{align*}
shows that, in display size, \verb|\extenint| is too small.

\end{document}
```

Again, the “right” `psyr.tfm` file must be loaded; if so, the output will look like the following:

[image: Output of the second code sample]

As you see, we have defined the `\extenint` command, which takes three arguments: the lower integration limit, the upper integration limit, and the integrand—or, at least, the part of it to the size of which the integral sign should conform.  This command typesets the integral sign in the appropriate size and with the specified limits, as well as the (part of the) integrand itself.  Note that, with this construction, it is not possible to add `\limits`, `\nolimits`, or `\displaylimits` to the integral sign; however, since we have loaded the *amsmath* package, we do honor its definition of `\ilimits@` in the code that defines the `\extenint` command.

Some further remarks are in order:

1. Appendix G of *The TeXbook* explains that, when the nucleus of an Op
   atom consists of a single character (which is the ordinary case),
   the limits for that atom are both shifted, in opposite directions,
   by half the amount of the italic correction for the character in
   question: see Rule 13a for the “`\limits` case” and Rule 18f for the
   “`\nolimits` case”, which coincides with the general rule applied to
   atoms which have both a subscript and a superscript.  This does
   *not* happen in our case, because the nucleus of our Op atom is not
   a single character.  We compensate for this by adding `\!` and `\,`
   in front of the subscript and of the superscript, respectively. 
   This simple correction seems to work pretty well both in the
   `\nolimits` and in the `\limits` case, but you might want to
   fine-tune the amount of kerning.
2. However, this corrections does not look adequate if the smaller
   integral sign happens to be chosen, at least in the `\nolimits`
   case.  This should probably be fixed.
3. Moreover, the bigger (and extensible) variant of the integral sign
   is not automatically chosen in display style, once again because the
   nucleus of the relevant Op atom is not a single character (see
   Rule 13).  This should be corrected too.

Maybe that someone (or even myself) will volunteer to write a well-crafted package that makes this extensible integral sign available, and in which all these issues are addressed.

But for now, I think this more than enough. (:-)

Comment: Very interesting! Why don't you just add the required fontdimen?

Comment: Do you mean, `\fontdimen7`?  Do you know if some package loads the Symbol font and, if so, whether it adds any `\fontdimen` parameter?

Comment: I don't think there are packages that use `psyr`. And setting the fontdimen should not be a big concern. However, I'd go for a different name.

Comment: Wow.  Very impressive.

Comment: Wonderfull solution, if you want to add support for optional sub- or superscripts, `xparse` may come in handy, so someone can write  \xint f(x) \d x` or `\xint_{D} <whatever> \d x`, etc. and that `\xint` takes everything until `\d` and measures. It could be messy at code level, but for the user may be simpler.