# Using Symbol font for extended integrals in LaTeX

Tags: fonts, symbols, integral

I wish to make my integral symbols in pdfLaTeX documents appear the same way as in the following example:

[image: Integral]

The integral symbol comes from the Symbol font which is shipped with Microsoft products, and is made by combining the unicode symbols 2320, 2321, and 23AE. Is it possible to replicate this symbol in pdfLatex or a related typesetting engine? And if so, could anyone suggest potential ways that I might accomplish this?

Comment: Welcome! pdfLaTeX: no. At least, as close to being no as makes no difference. Another typesetting engine: only if the font has the MATH table. Then you *might* be able to use `unicode-math` with XeTeX or LuaTeX. But don't hold your breath. Does the font have such a table? `otfinfo` can tell you or something like FontForge. If it does, you *might* be able to use the font for the maths in your document. But `unicode-math` is not the simple ride which the standard TeX fonts provide, so be prepared for bumps along the way.

Comment: I've never heard this font mentioned among those with a MATH table. As far as I know, it was just for symbols - a bit like Open Symbol or what have you. But I don't know anything about MS's current font offerings.

Comment: The font doesn't have a MATH table that I'm aware of (it is not even OpenType, being released in 1989), so it might not be possible by the sound of it. Thank you for your response in any case!

Comment: Just out of idle curiosity: *Why* do you wish to reproduce such a spindly, decrepit-looking integral symbol? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Maybe you're interested in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/254916/4427

Comment: @egreg That's why I said 'as close to being no as makes no difference' ;).

Comment: @Mico An excellent question. This spindly integral symbol is the one used in state-wide exam papers for high school students here in NSW, Australia. I'm not sure why it is used and have hardly even seen it used elsewhere, but would like to be able to use it myself when preparing notes or resources for consistency.

Comment: @Zac - Thanks! Since you ended your comment with the word "consistency", I can't resist throwing in a quote from Ralph Waldo Emerson: "A foolish consistency is the hobgoblin of little minds, adored by little statesmen and philosophers and divines." To be sure, I'm not insinuating that *your* attempt at achieving typographic consistency is necessarily foolish. All I mean to say is that "being consistent" is not some self-evident act of virtuousness. In particular, using a spindly-looking integral symbols should be justified in terms of its own merits -- which I seem unable to appreciate... :-)