# Integral with fraction and square root produces wrong vertical alignment

Tags: spacing, vertical-alignment, fractions, integral, sqrt

This code produces an ankward vertical alignment which involves the integral symbol and the fraction with the square root at the denominator. Why? How can I fix this?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
 \[
 \int_{x_0}^{x(t)} \! \! \! \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{2}{m}\bigl
 (E_0-V(x)\bigr)}} \, dx = t-t_0
 \]
\end{document}
```

Comment: What is awkward for you and how would you like it to look?

Comment: I've also tried using the "bigints" package to get a bigger integral symbol, but it doesn't do the job, in fact the symbol won't get aligned properly anyway...
Answering TeXnician: the integral symbol should be vertically aligned with the square root symbol at the denominator.

Comment: I still do not get what is awkward here? Do you refer to the integral sign having a smaller height than the fraction?

Comment: TeXnician exactly

Comment: The "\!" commands were not intended to be left in the code, I was trying to improve the spacing in some way and then forgot to remove them, so you can just ignore them.

Comment: Does any of the answers to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/251999/121799) help?

Comment: It looks mildly better with `\bigintss` (from [`bigints`](//ctan.org/pkg/bigints)).

Comment: I see nothing strange.

Comment: If it was not for the negative spaces and the non-upright differential d, I'd agree with @egreg.

Comment: marmot the question you linked was exactly what I wanted, thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's how it's supposed to be typeset.

Growing the integral symbol is out of the question, in my opinion. Moving it down is similarly disgraceful.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\noindent
No square root
 \[
 \int_{x_0}^{x(t)}
   \biggl(\frac{2}{m}\bigl(E_0-V(x)\bigr)\biggr)^{\!-1/2}\, dx = t-t_0
 \]
Smashed square root
 \[
 \int_{x_0}^{x(t)}
   \frac{1}{\sqrt{\smash[b]{\frac{2}{m}}(E_0-V(x))}} \, dx = t-t_0
 \]
Normal
 \[
 \int_{x_0}^{x(t)}
   \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{2}{m}\bigl(E_0-V(x)\bigr)}} \, dx = t-t_0
 \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I probably would do

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
 \[
 \int\limits_{x_0}^{x(t)}  \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{2}{m}\bigl
 (E_0-V(\xi)\bigr)}} \, \mathrm{d}\xi = t-t_0
 \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

to avoid confusion between the upper limit of the integral, `x(t)`, and the integration variable as well between some quantity `d` (like a diameter, say) and the differential `d`. `\int\limits` makes the integral symbol look higher.

Answer (score 1):

As marmot suggested, I tried using the scalerel package and I like the outcome. It's not perfect, but I think it's acceptable. The integral symbol is finally aligned with the bottom of the fraction.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{scalerel}

\begin{document}
 \def\x{\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{2}{m}\bigl(E_0-V
 (\xi)\bigr)}}}
 \[
 {\scalerel*[2.2ex]{\int}{\x}}_{\!\!\!x_0}^{\,x(t)}\x\,\,
 d\xi \, = \, t-t_0
 \]
\end{document}
```

[image]