# Is there a more typographically-satisfying bigints package?

Tags: math-mode, equations, symbols, bigdelim

I found the `bigints` package but as its documentation shows, the symbol is simply scaled up in size which leads to a much thicker stroke:
[image]

Is there a package that deals with this properly, or failing that, can someone sketch out how I could achieve the correct result, maybe with some TikZ wizardry? I only want the basic integral sign, not `oint` or anything else.

Comment: Possibly related: [Arbitrary `\left` `\right` delimiters](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/254916/69818).

Comment: My `scalerel` package allows math scaling and/or stretching, with width and/or aspect limiters, respectively.  See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/251999/arbitrary-left-right-delimiters, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/104414/math-spacing-in-tex-gyre-pagella, for example.  Whether it is aesthetically called for, however, is in question.

Comment: @CalvinKhor Do not delete it, please. However, if you are sure that is a duplicate then use the "flag" link below your question and mark it as duplicate.